# How to get timezone abbreviation with date-fns-tz?

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns, date-fns-tz

I have an ISO string in UTC from my backend and I want to format it to particular timezone so I am using `date-fns-tz` for that as recommended in the docs

But when I try to print the date with timezone abbreviation token, I get the `GMT+/-x` instead of the timezone abbreviation instead

```js
import formatInTimeZone from 'date-fns-tz/formatInTimeZone';
...

const timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
const formattedDate = formatInTimeZone(parsedStartDate, timezone, 'dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a z');
// fomattedDate -> 04 June 2023 09:00 AM GMT+5:30
```

As [recommended by docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz) I also tried adding locale, and when I add a locale it works for the timezones that belong to that locale but doesn't work for others. For instance, if I add en-IN locale to the previous example it shows `IST` correctly but it still shows `GMT+/-x` for other European/American timezones

```js
import formatInTimeZone from 'date-fns-tz/formatInTimeZone';
import enIN from 'date-fns/locale/en-IN';
...

const timezone = "Asia/Calcutta";
const formattedDate = formatInTimeZone(parsedStartDate, timezone, 'dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm a z'  { locale: enIN });
// fomattedDate -> 04 June 2023 09:00 AM IST
```

I really don't understand why it works this way, and want to know if I am missing something